# Is there a Linux distro, which has better support for newer Python modules, compared to others?

Tags: python, module, linux-distro

I prefer, where possible, to use Python environment and modules that are provided by the Linux distro.

Is there any distro that is known, or even perhaps claims that one of their priorities is, to test and integrate newer versions of Python and popular Python modules into their package system?

This is related to [What linux distro is better suited for Python web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021803/what-linux-distro-is-better-suited-for-python-web-development), but I am not interested in web development, rather like in modules such as Pandas/numpy, IMAPclient, lxml, xlrd.

Comment: You shouldn't be installing modules via your distro's package management system; you should use pip for that.

Comment: No, there are some distro with pre-installed libraries, but you should only have the libraries what you have to use

Comment: @DanielRoseman Aren't there python modules and extensions that are not written in Python and not covered by PIP?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. If they're Python modules, they are installable via pip, even if they contain C extensions for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** "Python-oriented" distro as all of them come pre-packaged with Python, although not with the latest modules.
The reasons for not bundling the OS with all the newer Python modules are rather simple and rational:

- They require more space on the disk and
- Most of the packages have dependencies
- Fresh packages may have bugs that can compromise the OS or other modules

From a developer's perspective, it is a lot easier to start with a minimal Python installation and then install your desired packages rather than starting with a system bloated with all sorts of packages and modules and having to downgrade or get rid of some of them to get to your desired versions.